# Finding webelements nested in HTML <div> tags with selenium using headless browser

Tags: html, selenium, nested, htmlunit, headless

I am trying to automate entering a username, password then hit submit to log in to the web page using a headless browser but the html code for the textbox webelement is not visible right off the webpage.

With selenium webdriver with headless browser HtmlUnitDriver, I am trying to do a findElementBy on a webelement that is nested inside .  When I view the HTML straight from the web page, the body looks like the below.  When I bring up the developer tools using Google Chrome, I can see that the html code for the textbox (webelement), which looks something like , that I am trying to find is nested within the  tags.  Is there any way that I can find the textbox webelement nested within those div tags so that I can input my username using selenium?

I have tried to research several approaches like using JavascriptExecutor to maybe expand the contents of div in the html that is returned from the webpage but that didnt work, maybe I had the wrong javascript written. I have also tried Jsoup but the Jsoup parse function needs to parse the html as a String, not as a Document(webpage containing webelements that I can find and enter text into).

I should also note that in the below files with .js extension, I did a ctrl+f to find the words "gui-view", "username" and "password" in example2.js

```
   <body>
        <div gui-view></div>
       <script src="example1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <script src="example2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

      <script src="//some.path.net/example3.js"></script>
      <script>try{TipK.load();}catch(e){}</script>
   </body>

   </html>
```

Comment: There shouldn't be an issue with this.  If you can't figure it out, install "Selenium Builder" , make a recording, then export it to a format for HtmlUnitDriver .   It might reveal something you are missing.

Comment: I think in your question you pasted the html code for the element that you see in Chrome but it's not showing - is it in a code block? If you can display the html you see in Chrome, we can give feedback on how to create a locator.

Comment: Yes i can get the html path by using Google developer tools on the webpage.  However, performing a page source off the webpage in google chrome, the body of the webpage's html looks something like what i posted originally. Meaning the html path is now hidden within <div gui-view></div> and not shown when i do page source

@john-o

my java code looks something like

 HtmlUnitDriver driver = new          HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
  driver.get("https://website.com/#/auth/login");
  driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
  driver.findElement(By.name("username")).clear();

Comment: the error is 

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element with name: username
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Comment: @djangofan in the quotes of driver.get is https://website.com/#/auth/login

Answer (score 1):

Reading your comments I think you need to revise your understanding of where elements live. All elements live in the DOM that exists in browser memory. They are all in the browser. Absolutely no elements live on the server. If you're not sure what the DOM is, think of it as the page you see in your browser.

The browser DOM is active. Elements can come and go. The browser has a running javascript engine. Javascript files sent from the server give the engine instructions on how to change the DOM.

When Selenium is throwing the NoSuchElement exception it is because it cannot find the element in the DOM. It is not looking in any files. You do not need to give it any files. You just need to present it with the browser DOM in the correct state.

In your case there is a javascript event attached to the username element to only appear once a user clicks on the first 'SIGN IN' link. You need to trigger that event to make the username element appear. To work out how to do that, **follow your own thought process as you manually do stuff on the page**. i.e. make sure you click the 'SIGN IN' link so that the username field appears. If you can't enter a username without seeing it then neither can Selenium.

Be careful about which developer tool you use to view the DOM. *Page Source* shows you the original html sent to the browser. It is not a full picture of the DOM. If javascript is used to build any elements on the page you will not see those elements in the *Page Source*.

To see the html for the active DOM use *Inspect Element* instead.

Now you've shared the url, we can see the full html of the page. As outlined in the other answer, you'll need to:

1. Click on the 'SIGN IN' button `By.xpath("//a[@id='memberFunction']")` to expose the username and password fields
2. Wait for the username field to appear
3. Enter text in the username field `By.xpath("//input[@id='username']")`
4. Enter text in the password field `By.xpath("//input[@id='password']")`
5. Click on the 'Sign In' button `By.xpath("//a[@id='signinSubmit']")`

Comment: my java code looks something like

 HtmlUnitDriver driver = new          HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
  driver.get("https://website.com");
  driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
  driver.findElement(By.name("username")).clear();

Comment: the username and password textboxes are loaded together with the main page. my code looks like this 
    HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
  driver.get("https://google.com");
  driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
  Thread.sleep(10000);
  System.out.println("The page response is " + driver.getCurrentUrl());
  Thread.sleep(100000);
  WebElement username_enter = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//section[@id='login-form']"));
  System.out.println("The element is " + username_enter);

I changed the website to google.com for the example.

Comment: when using a physical browser in selenium, the element is found using the xpath provided.  however, with the headless browser HtmlUnitDriver, it cannot find the xpath.

Comment: I'm confused. I thought you were testing with "http://website.com". Now you're saying it's "http://google.com". Can you edit your question to include the Java code you're actually using?

Comment: i just put google.com because i cannot disclose the actual web page that I am testing.  I have actually resorted to using phantomjs driver, it seems as though the website does not run properly on htmlunitdriver @JohnO.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it is pretty clear (using [FirePath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firepath/) plugin for Firefox) that you wont be able to enter a username with Selenium unless you do something like the following pseudo-code:

1. Navigate to https://www.website.com/#member
2. element.click(By.xpath(".//a[@id='memberFunction']")); // triggers DOM change
3. element.click(By.id("username"));
4. element.sendKeys(By.id("username"), "whatever"));

Comment: i tried this and its not working. if you see the code i posted i am finding element by name and it is not finding the element.  but i think it may be because the elements live on the server on some php or javascript file, not the html page.

Comment: That is not possible.  What I think is happening is that when you click on the page the DOM is dynamically changing.  This is normal and you just need to make sure that you do the proper actions on the page to setup the DOM so that finding the element will succeed.   Also, try increasing the "default implicit wait" to 1 second since the default is 0: I am guessing it would reveal the problem if you did that (although I recommend you generally don't change that value and use explicit waits instead).

Comment: @johno. Would this hold true to a browser that is headless as well?

Comment: Yes, it holds true of selenium, in general.